# JSON Object, undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to develop a web application using jQuery, AJAX and JSON.
I have this code:

```
console.log(response.s);
if (response.s == true) {
    alert('good');
} else {
    alert('bad');
}
```

This `response` (via `console.log()` on Firebug) seems to be:

```
{"s":true}
```

Which seems to be a JSON object right?
Well, the line `console.log(response.s);` on the first code I added here returns `undefined`. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you click the {"s":true} object within Firebug console and see it in object (DOM) explorer or is it written as string in the Firebug console (i.e. not clickable)?

Comment: @Nikhil, i guess it more like a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is `typeof (response)`? if it's a string then you have to parse it, first. (You'd be accessing the `s` field of a string, which doesn't exist, so JavaScript gives you `undefined` instead of throwing an Exception or whatever.)

Comment: How can i check the type of it? How could i parse it?

Comment: literally type in `typeof (response.s)` in the console. or type in `response.s.constructor` and see what that gives you.

Comment: I think you meant to ask about `typeof response`. If that returns "string", OP needs to call `jQuery.parseJSON( response )`

Comment: Yes it was a string. I just added `dataType: 'json'` to my ajax jQuery request and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the `content-type` of the response isn't `application/json` then the javascript is probably assuming that it is just a string.

Supplying the correct content header should therefore sort your problem.

Alternatively you could probably use `eval()` to convert the string into a json object.

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(obj.s);
```

Hope it helps.